# Libre office Calc - tables, numbers and formulas?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a lot of numbers located in a table, there are thousands of numbers in there (30 columns × 250 rows). I want to know is there any function to find least frequent number/numbers in the whole table?

Should I use some function to to that or any other methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `frequency()`function to find the frequency of any number or a range of numbers in a table.
[LibreOffice help contains an example on how to use the function.](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions#FREQUENCY)